# how to count repeated characters in a string in python

Tags: python, string, list

Write a python function which performs the run length encoding for a given String and returns the run length encoded String.

I tried it using looping but couldn't get the expected output.

```
def encode(message):    
    #Remove pass and write your logic here
    count=0
    encoded_message=[]
    for char in range(0,len(message)-1,1):
        count=1
        while(message[char]==message[char+1]):

             count=count+1;
             char=char+1
        encoded_message.append(str(count)+message[char])

    return encoded_message

encoded_message=encode("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB")
print(' '.join(encoded_message))
```

expected output is `1A4B8C1A1B`.
what I got is `1A 4B 3B 2B 1B 8C 7C 6C 5C 4C 3C 2C 1C 1A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fix your function, here is fixed variant:

```
def encode(message):
    result = []
    i = count = 0
    while i < len(message) - 1:
        count = 1
        while i + count < len(message) and message[i + count - 1] == message[i + count]:
            count += 1
        i += count
        result.append("{}{}".format(count, message[i - 1]))
    if count == 1:
        result.append("1" + message[-1])
    return result
```

What's changed:

1. **for** loop replaced with **while**. Why? Cause you need to jump over indexes incide loop. `range(0,len(message)-1,1)` returns you list `[0, 1, 2, ...]` and it doesn't matter what you do with `char` variable incide loop, it won't affect next iteration. To have a possibility skip some indexes I used **while** loop with predefined ( `i = count = 0` ) index and count variables.
2. Changed conditions of internal **while** loop. Now there're two conditions:

   - `message[i + count - 1] == message[i + count]` - check if next symbol same with current;
   - `i + count < len(message)` - prevent intenal loop from accessing index out of range.
3. Updating "main" index ( `i` ) outside of internal loop.
4. `if count == 1:` added post condition after loop execution to not miss last character in case if it's single.

Comment: class codechef { 
    public static void printRLE(String str) 
    { 
    int n = str.length(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
     int count = 1; 
            while (i < n - 1 &&  
                   str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1)) { 
                count++; 
                i++; 
            } 
            System.out.print(count); 
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i)); 
           } 
    } 
  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String str = "AABCCA"; 
        printRLE(str); 
    } 
} i got the answer with same logic using java

Comment: @ganeshchandra, what is that?

Comment: i used the same logic and wrote the program in java ,it worked fine and got the correct output

Comment: @ganeshchandra, how does it connected to my answer?

Comment: well the if the logic is same then it should work fine ,you said char=char+1 doesnt skip the iterations but it did when the program is in java but not in ptyhon

Comment: @ganeshchandra, but I've said it about python code. You java code is not the same as python. In python `for` equals java `foreach`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` module :

```
s = "ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB"
from itertools import groupby
expected = ''.join([str(len(list(v)))+k for k,v in groupby(s)])
```

**Output** :

```
'1A4B8C1A1B'
```

`groupby(s)` returns a `itertools.groupby` object. A list comprehension on this object like `[(k,list(v)) for k,v in groupby(s)]` returns us this in ordered way :

```
[('A', ['A']), ('B', ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']), ('C', ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']), ('A', ['A']), ('B', ['B'])]
```

We can just count the number of sub-items in the second-item of the tuple and add its string format before the first item of the tuple and join all of them.

**Update** :
You are trying to change the iteration index in the loop by doing `char=char+1` but it doesn't change the iteration index i.e. the loop doesn't pass for the next 2 or 3 or 4 iterations. Add these two print lines in your code and you would see that the `char` variable you're trying to increase while looping is not simply the iteration index  :

```
...
for char in range(0,len(message)-1,1):
        print('\tchar at first line : ', char, 'char id now : ', id(char))
        count=1
        while(message[char]==message[char+1]):
            count=count+1
            char=char+1
            print('char now : ', char, 'char id now : ', id(char))
            ...
```

It should output something like :

```
    char at first line :  1 char id now :  11197408
char now :  2 char id now :  11197440
char now :  3 char id now :  11197472
char now :  4 char id now :  11197504
```

See, how the `id` of each time `char` got changed.

Comment: It would help the understanding if you could write your 3rd line in a bit more lines (atomic).

Comment: the last line can be simplified to `expected = ''.join([f'{len(list(v))}{k}' for k,v in groupby(s)])`

Comment: can u please tell me whats is wrong in my code,i know the loop messed it up but i want to know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `re` module for encoding the string:

```
s = 'ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB'

import re

l = ''.join(str(len(c2)+1) + c1 for c1, c2 in re.findall(r'([A-Z])(\1*)', s))

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
1A4B8C1A1B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(string):
    string +='@'
    dic = []
    tmp =[]
    tmp += [string[0]]

    for i in range(1,len(string)):

        if string[i]==string[i-1]:
            tmp.append(string[i])
        else:
            dic.append(tmp)
            tmp=[]
            tmp.append(string[i])
    res = ''.join(['{}{}'.format(len(i),i[0]) for i in dic])
    return res

string = 'ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB'         
solution = func(string)

print(solution)
```

output

```
1A4B8C1A1B
```

Comment: It doesn't produced expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic, it will return you a dictionary with frequency of each letter.

```
s = "ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB"
d = {i:0 for i in s}
for i in s:
    d[i] += 1
print(d)
```

---

```
**output:-**
{'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 8}
```